# Possible bug in Caret function predict.gb()?

Tags: r, predict, r-caret, gbm

It seems to me that I’ve discovered a bug in the performance of the predict() function for method=gbm in the Caret package in R.  I'm curious to know if others agree, or if someone has an explanation for the behavior of this function.

**1. Generate data**

```
library(caret)

x1 <- rnorm(100)

x2 <- rnorm(100, 2)

y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(100)

df <- data.frame(x1=x1, x2=x2,  y=y)
```

**2.  Predict using method="lm"**

The following code works as expected: using method=“lm” the two predicted values match.  In the first case, p1, “y” is included in newdata, in the second case, p2, it is not.

```
tempd <- df[1:99, c("y", "x1", "x2") ]

newdata <- df[100, c("y", "x1", "x2")]

lm.fit <- train(y~x1 + x2, data=tempd, method="lm")

p1 <- predict(lm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata)

newdata <- df[100, c("x1", "x2")]

p2 <- predict(lm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata)
```

p1 should equal p2, and does:

```
p1==p2
```

**3.  Predict using method="gbm"**

This code does not work as expected:  using method=“gbm,” with the identical set up, the two predicted values do not match.

```
tempd <- df[1:99, c("y","x1","x2")]

newdata <- df[100, c("y","x1","x2")]

gbm.fit <- train(y~x1+x2 , data=tempd, method="gbm", verbose=F)

p1 <- predict(gbm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata,
          n.trees=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,                       
          interaction.depth=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$interaction.depth,
          shrinkage=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$shrinkage)

newdata <- df[100, c("x1","x2")]

p2 <- predict(gbm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata,
          n.trees=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,                  
          interaction.depth=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$interaction.depth,
          shrinkage=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$shrinkage)
```

In this case, p1 does not equal p2:

```
p1==p2
```

**4.  Predict using method="gbm" with a different set up**

BUT, curiously, with one small change—not explicitly naming the variables in the subset operation--it does work:

```
tempd <- df[1:99, ]

newdata <- df[100, ]

gbm.fit <- train(y~x1+x2 , data=tempd, method="gbm", verbose=F)

p1 <- predict(gbm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata,
          n.trees=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,                                         
          interaction.depth=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$interaction.depth,
          shrinkage=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$shrinkage)

newdata <- df[100, c("x1","x2")]

p2 <- predict(gbm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata,
          n.trees=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,                  
          interaction.depth=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$interaction.depth,
          shrinkage=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$shrinkage)

p1==p2
```

Thanks in advance for our thoughts.

Jeff

Comment: Is there a reason for you to not follow the "normal" use of `predict`, such as `predict(gbm.fit, newdata=newdata)`?

Answer (score 2):

As @Pascal pointed out, you're skipping an important step. Rather than calling `predict()` on the finalModel value, you should be calling `predict` on the `gmb.fit` object directly. Note

```
class(gbm.fit)
# [1] "train"         "train.formula"
class(gbm.fit$finalModel)
# [1] "gbm"
```

Since these objects have different classes, they trigger different underlying prediction function. The important part is that `predict.train` reshapes the `newdata` to the correct format for the `gbm` predictor. Without this data reshaping, you will get the incorrect results (the predictor expects the columns to be in a certain order)

Observe

```
newdata1 <- df[100, c("y","x1","x2")]
newdata2 <- df[100, c("x1","x2")]
newdata3 <- df[100, ]

predict(gbm.fit, newdata1)
# [1] 1.427069
predict(gbm.fit, newdata2)
# [1] 1.427069
predict(gbm.fit, newdata3)
# [1] 1.427069

predict(gbm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata1,
          n.trees=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,                  
          interaction.depth=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$interaction.depth,
          shrinkage=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$shrinkage)
# [1] 2.166468
predict(gbm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata2,
          n.trees=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,                  
          interaction.depth=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$interaction.depth,
          shrinkage=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$shrinkage)
# [1] 1.427069
predict(gbm.fit$finalModel, newdata=newdata3,
          n.trees=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$n.trees,                  
          interaction.depth=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$interaction.depth,
          shrinkage=gbm.fit$finalModel$tuneValue$shrinkage)
# [1] 1.427069
```

So if you're going to use the `train()` function to fit your model, be sure to use the proper `predict.train` function to correctly make predictions from the model.